# How can I push the text inside a custom spinner to the right?

Tags: android, xml

I have created a custom spinner like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item><layer-list>
<item><shape>
<gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff"android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

</shape></item>
<item ><bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/spinnerdropdownarrow" />
    </item>
</layer-list></item>
```

I want to set the text inside align to the right side, how can I do that?
Where should I set the gravity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your own layout for spinner item.

```
SpinnerAdapter adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});
spriner.setAdapter(adap);
```

Where R.layout.spinner_item is a layout with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:text="Sample Text" 
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" 
    android:paddingTop="5dp"></TextView>
```

Comment: If I have an string-array inside the string.xml, how do i call it and put it and replace the new String[]{"A", "B", "C"} ?
I've tried R.array.addclaim_type
but it says Expected resource of type id

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom layout with TextView and give its gravity right.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity"right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

And use this layout in Spinner as resource.

```html
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.your_created_custom_layout);
```

Comment: If I got a string-array that keeps the result in my string.xml, and I already set the entries of the spinner to my string-array. How do I simply set an adapter for my spinner?

Comment: No need to change any other code. It is the same as it was passing string array in ArrayAdapter.